# Embedding should have been able to show the button

Tags: javascript, domdocument, document.write

Please be advised that the following codes are generated by an engineer. (I don't have contact with the engineer right now)

Now here is the scenario. According to the engineer who had created this the whole collection of these scripts should be able to generate a button once edited properly and embedded to our website.

Before I implement this on our own website I want to test these codes to a simple page created through saving codes from our website. I ask the engineer if it is possible and he said yes.

Now here is the code that should be able to generate the button.

clickCall.js

```
  (function () {
var createScriptElement = function (src, onload, onerror) {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.type = "text\/javascript";
        element.src = src;
        element.onload = onload;
        element.onerror = onerror;
        return element;
};


var createLinkElement = function (src) {
    var element = document.createElement('link');
    element.href = src;
    element.rel = 'Stylesheet';
    element.media_type = 'text/css';
    return element;
};
var createUI = function () {
    var clickCallDiv = document.createElement('div');
    clickCallDiv.style.cssText = 'width: 300px;height: 60px;position: fixed;z-index: 999;right: 20px;bottom: 320px;';
    var call_btn = document.createElement("button");
    call_btn.id = "dial_btn_call";
    var session_div = document.createElement("div");
    session_div.id = 'sessions';
    var webcam_div = document.createElement("div");
    webcam_div.style.cssText = 'height:0';
    webcam_div.id = 'webcam';
    var video_remote = document.createElement('video');
    video_remote.id = 'remoteView';
    video_remote.autoplay = 'autoplay';
    video_remote.hidden = 'hidden';
    var video_local = document.createElement('video');
    video_local.autoplay = 'autoplay';
    video_local.hidden = 'hidden';
    video_local.muted = 'muted';
    video_local.id = 'selfView';
    webcam_div.appendChild(video_remote);
    webcam_div.appendChild(video_local);

    clickCallDiv.appendChild(call_btn); //add the text node to the newly created div.
    var contain = document.createElement('div');
    contain.appendChild(session_div);
    contain.appendChild(webcam_div);
    clickCallDiv.appendChild(contain);
    return clickCallDiv;
};
var urls = {};
urls.rtcninja = 'rtcninja.js';
urls.jquery = 'jquery.js';
urls.i18n = "jquery.i18n.js";
urls.messagestore = "jquery.i18n.messagestore.js";
urls.jssip = 'jssip.js';
urls.init = 'init.js';
urls.gui = 'gui.js';
urls.css = 'style.css';



var rtcninja_script = createScriptElement(urls.rtcninja, function () {
    // Must first init the library
    rtcninja();
    // Then check.
    if (!rtcninja.hasWebRTC()) {
        console.log('WebRTC is not supported in your browser :(');
    } else {
        document.body.appendChild(createUI());
    }
});

var jquery_script = createScriptElement(urls.jquery, function(){
    document.head.appendChild(i18_script);
    document.head.appendChild(jssip_script);
    document.head.appendChild(gui_script);
    document.head.appendChild(init_script);
});
var i18_script = createScriptElement(urls.i18n, function(){
    document.head.appendChild(messagestore_script);
});
var messagestore_script = createScriptElement(urls.messagestore);
var jssip_script = createScriptElement(urls.jssip);
var init_script = createScriptElement(urls.init);
var gui_script = createScriptElement(urls.gui);
var click_call_css = createLinkElement(urls.css);

document.head.appendChild(jquery_script);
document.head.appendChild(rtcninja_script);
document.head.appendChild(click_call_css);
})();
```

That script, when embedded, should be able to generate a button. The way he embedded the script on their website is through this

```
<script>
document.write('<script src="sourcefile/clickCall.js">/script>')
</script>
```

But this won't work on my side so I tried this

```
document.write('<sc' + 'ript src="clickCall.js">/sc' + 'ript>')
```

Now my first problem is that this script prevents all other scripts from loading, causing to have an empty output. another is that it won't display the expected button that it was suppose to show on the webpage. My solution to this problems was to implement DOM but I don't know how I'll implement it especially because I can't understand how it works and how to implement it. Could you kindly explain to me how DOM works and how am I going to implement it? Thanks

Comment: Your modification of the script element is pointless, the bit that matters is `</`. Is *sourcefile/clickCall.js* the correct path to the file? What does "*My solution ... was to implement DOM*" mean?

Comment: what happens here is that the first `</script>` happens to close the `<script>` before the document. It results to printing `')` instead.

Comment: In that case use `document.write('<script src="clickCall.js"><\/script>')`, i,e. just quote the slash in `</script>` (note that there is a typo in the OP, the closing tag is not correct).

Comment: I'll tell you what, it would print `')` if you enclose it with `<`

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: `</script>` would close the first `<script>` :)

Comment: of course it would. And that's the point of it. Where else do you close it? And if you don't want to close it, what's the purpose of the ``/script>``?

Comment: what i mean here is that once you made it like this `document.write('<script src="sourcefile/clickCall.js"></script>')` it would close the `<script>` above the 'document.write` which result to printing `')' instead of actually performing the script itself. I've tried configuring that one, but as the engineer had told me, the code should be fine. And as stated on the problem, the script prevents all other java script from execution. Thus, no output is seen once you embed it. Now @f1sh since i think you are experienced enough, I think you should be able to know how to implement DOM?

Comment: Actually I had already implemented DOM. Thanks to my colleagues who explained it to me further. Now I just have to contact the engineer for further debugging of the system itself. I think you're not familiar with the other ways to implement object-oriented programming itself like DOM? ok @f1sh thanks for the mark down when you don't even understand it.

Answer (score 0):

*document.write* when executed just writes the string and doesn't execute the inside script.

Hence, instead of this,

```
<script>
document.write('<script src="sourcefile/clickCall.js"></script>')
```

you can directly call your script.

```
<script src="sourcefile/clickCall.js"></script>
```

Comment: As stated here http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write It is convenient, but a bad way, because loading a script may block the rest of page from rendering. Especially, a problem when the ads server is slow.

Comment: And by the way, what I need here is to know how I'll implement DOM and not how to directly call the script

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by "implementing DOM" ?

Comment: DOM is a way of implementing a script in a manner that it would not block other js of the page.

Comment: I didn't get your terming.. Did you mean to say an implementation to run js in non blocking way?

Comment: Yes. Such thing should not block the js or no output would be displayed.